# MacBook Pro (mid 2012) does not detect internal screen

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hardware

I have an old MacBook Pro 13 which does not react as it should. after a liquid damage i have changed the display. Unfortunately it only recognizes the internal display when I connect an external one.

The workflow looks like this:

1. boot up: black monitor
2. plug in an external monitor
3. external monitor is detected
4. log in to Mac OS
5. successfully logged in -> the internal display is re-activated and works as it should

---

- The display is not deactivated, it is illuminated, but shows nothing
  (only black)
- Tried to re-connecting the battery connector from the logic-board
- I resetted SMC and NVRAM several times.
- Hard disk was formatted and the latest version of Catalina 10.15.1 was installed.
- The internal display does not activate if I log in without an external display.
- The system loses the display when I restart.

**Any ideas?**

--
note: before the display change everything did work as it should.